# why detected recursion whilst expanding macro "inline"?

Tags: linux, gcc, kernel

I am building 32-bit (i386) linux kernel on a x86_64 linux host. Both host and target version is 2.6.9.  I am doing the following from the linux source tree:

```
make ARCH=i386 CFLAGS='-m32 -Iinclude/asm/mach-default' AFLAGS='--32'  menuconfig
make ARCH=i386 CFLAGS='-m32 -Iinclude/asm/mach-default' AFLAGS='-m32 -Iinclude/asm/mach-default'
```

I would hit the following error from the 2nd make:

```
  AS      arch/i386/kernel/entry.o
In file included from include/linux/bitops.h:4,
                 from include/asm/cpufeature.h:10,
                 from include/asm/processor.h:16,
                 from include/asm/thread_info.h:16,
                 from arch/i386/kernel/entry.S:45:
include/asm/bitops.h:42: detected recursion whilst expanding macro "inline"
```

The line 42 in bitops.h reads like this:

```
static inline void set_bit(int nr, volatile unsigned long * addr)
```

Since gcc supports inline functions, I don't understand why this "inline" was treated as macro,  and how come there is recursion expanding "inline"?

my gcc version is:

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-11)
```

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: By the error message, the keyword `inline` has been overridden with a macro (which is undefined behaviour). It's probably something like `#define inline __attribute__((inline))`, since the preprocessor complains that it's recursive. Check out the `#define`.

Comment: My guess: `inline` is defined somewhere else as a macro so the build can be configured to make inline functions or not (by defining it to "inline" or "").  Seems easy to get a recursive expansion problem here, but I don't know why you'd get that on an unmodified source tree.

Comment: indeed there are definitions like this: # define inline  inline  __attribute__((always_inline)) in compiler-gcc3.h and  compiler-gcc+.h. However, based on the rule of "Self-Referential Macros", it should not cause any problem.

Comment: by the way,  could it be that the rule of "Self-Referential Macros" was disabled for some reason?

Comment: Just to follow up, I found that the errors are basically caused by the mismatch of gcc and the kernel versions. The kernel asks for gcc version 2.95.3 but my gcc is 3.4.6. Eventually I moved to a Linux 2.6.24 that requires gcc 3.2 then all errors are gone :-)